# Display mail size in Gmail

Tags: gmail

As I'm running out of space I need to delete space wasting mails. Is there any option in Gmail that adds a size column in the mail list or even sorts them by size?

Comment: Almost duplicate of: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/how-can-i-sort-emails-in-gmail-by-size

Comment: If you don't trust third-party sites to keep your Gmail credentials safe you can use the following guide to build a spreadsheet in Google Docs containing a list of your large emails...
http://www.labnol.org/internet/sort-gmail-by-size/21191/

Comment: This answer will have absolutely no value if the link no longer functions.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. he specifically asked for a size column. The answer is apparently no.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Gmail now supports searching by size: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190

The new operators are:

- `size:` — Search for messages larger than the specified size in bytes

  - Example: `size:1000000`
  - Meaning: All messages larger than 1MB (1,000,000 bytes) in size.
- `larger:` and `smaller:` — Similar to `size:` but allows abbreviations for numbers

  - Example: `larger:10M`
  - Meaning: All messages of at least 10M bytes (10,000,000 bytes) in size.

You can now search for emails of that size and delete any to free up space.

Comment: this also doesn't answer the question. he specifically asked for a size column.

Answer (score 6):

You can try [Find Big Mail](http://www.findbigmail.com/).

Finds big emails in your Gmail account and then tags them for you, so you can find spot them easily.

Comment: "FindBigMail, [...], is down and will remain so for a while"