# Find largest email messages in Gmail

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sort emails in GMail by size?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/how-can-i-sort-emails-in-gmail-by-size)

I am trying to reduce my Gmail footprint and thus need to locate the largest emails.

I am aware of [FindBigMail](https://www.findbigmail.com/), but they charge and would like to know if there is a way to do this inside of Gmail or there may be some free solution.

Answer (score 4):

it has been quite sometime since i used it so you need to read the current info.

you can mount google gmail as a fuse filesystem in linux, and then you can just use the find command.

http://wiki.vpslink.com/Mount_a_Gmail_Account_as_a_FUSE_Filesystem

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to get a free IMAP client such as Thunderbird and use that to sort your emails by size. When using IMAP any mail you delete from the client can also be purged from the server.

You would also need to enable IMAP access from your GMail options.

Comment: Thunderbird is excellent for this sort of thing. I use it all the time for managing large amounts of email. It can sort, filter and manipulate email so much more quickly and effectively than the GMail web-app. In case it's not obvious, to sort by size, just right-click on the columns and check 'size'. You now have a size column to sort on. 

Bonus-tip: the [Nostalgy][1] extension makes Thunderbird even more efficient.

[1]: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/nostalgy/

Answer (score 4):

Google's response that I've seen in the support forums is that they do searching, not sorting.  So the key is to search for attachments that are likely to be large.  In the search box, try entering this string (or modify for your own list of extensions):

```
filename:(mpg OR mpeg OR avi OR wmv OR zip OR rar OR bmp OR mp3 OR wma OR mov)
```

This should return only messages with one of these attachments, which you can then choose to delete.

[Source](http://www.mattsilverman.com/2010/01/sort-gmail-by-attachment-size.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you have an account that ends in @gmail.com, FindBigMail is free. See https://www.findbigmail.com/pricing for info. Alternatively, if you've access to a Windows machine, you could try IMAPSize: http://www.broobles.com/imapsize/

Answer (score 2):

I found this Google docs trick that may be what you are looking for:
http://www.labnol.org/internet/sort-gmail-by-size/