# How can I create a filter for large attachments in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sort emails in GMail by size?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/how-can-i-sort-emails-in-gmail-by-size)

In Gmail, how can I create a filter that will forward messages with an attachments larger than say 10MB to another account?

Answer (score 3):

Gmail has [officially started supporting search by size](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/search-for-emails-by-size-and-more-in.html), it means you can create a filter with `size:20m` to filter (and/or forward) all emails greater than 20 MB.

---

<strike>Gmail does not support searching / sorting on attachment size.</strike> It does however allow you to [search and filter](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) on attachment type `(has:attachment filename:pdf)`, that may work if you can isolate your large mails on file name/extension.

An alternate - but not very neat - way to do that would involve setting up your [Gmail in desktop client as IMAP](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77689) and move it to specific folder (label) or forward it to another account.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no filter that can do this I have looked into a service that can help: [find big mail](https://www.findbigmail.com)

It will identify your largest emails. It is free for @gmail.com accounts