# How can I see how much space a label or folder is taking up in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Is there a way to see how how much space a label/folder is taking up on Gmail ?

I know I can see the overall account info at the bottom i.e., "x of 15gb" - but is there a way to break this down by folder or label?

Comment: It would be a great feature but AFAIK it doesn't exist in Gmail. Also, it would be misleading because if you have multiple labels on an email, the total sum of all labels would be far greater than the actual size. Still, I'd be interested in a web tool that would provide that info.

Comment: Just a thought i suppose you could connect to gmail using an imap client that allowed you to see the size of folders (not sure if there are any that let you do that though)

Comment: I've definitely been down the IMAP road before. I can find the exact software I had used, but if you have access to a Windows machine, this might do the trick: http://www.broobles.com/imapsize/

Comment: Oh, and perhaps not what you're looking for, but answers to this question might be useful too: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2282/41003

Comment: You can't do it with web client. You need to use some IMAP client to accomplish this.

Comment: One problem is that a message can have several labels attached to it. Where, then, do you "count" that message?

Comment: https://www.findbigmail.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is currently not possible with GMail web interface. As a workaround I would suggest using any IMAP client.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but by far the easiest solution for me - a MacOS user - was to use MacOS Mail - an application I traditionally don't use for gMail access. However as an earlier email suggests, by default it chooses to use the IMAP protocal to interact with gMail. And so via its standard "Account Info" menu option, you get a folder by folder breakdown including a) Number of Emails per label, and b) Size of Each label. Now for me - I use a fair number of hierarchically arranged labels, so it may not on occasion be 100% obvious what some of the labels are - because it doesn't show the higher level labels ... But it certainly shows the size of each folder - and the listing produced can be sorted by this size. But, it does take some time to create, as - obviously - it is traversing your complete email repository to do so.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to do a search, and download an archive with your past search. A lengthy process but will let you know at the end.

Answer (score -2):

Why not simply do the following:

1. Make sure your 'bin' is empty
2. write down your current storage (e.g 13 GB)
3. delete all mails in the desired folder/label
4. see how much storage is left (let's say 11.8 GB)
5. the folder space is 13-11.8= 1.2 GB
6. restore your deleted folder (all the 'bin' content)

Comment: Pretty sure the contents of the Trash bucket count against your storage.

Comment: First it will NOT reduce the storage if the mails are still in Trash. Second if you move it to Trash and then its not easy to select the mails & move back to Label, unless the trash was empty.

Answer (score -2):

You could also go into settings/labels and view how many conversations are saved under each label.